# Passing the counter of a for loop to queue()?

Tags: jquery, queue

I am trying to use the value of a for loop counter inside a queued function, for example:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
   $(document.body).queue(function(){alert('i=' + i); $(this).dequeue();}).delay(1000);
```

then I get:

```
i=0, i=5, i=5, i=5, i=5
```

I think this is because `i` has changed while `delay(1000)`..
What can I do to get the right values of `i`, i.e:

```
 i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3, i=4
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a closure e.g:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    $(document.body).queue(returnFromQueue(i)).delay(1000);

function returnFromQueue(i) {
    return function () {
        alert('i=' + i);
        $(this).dequeue();
    }
}
```